# How to create and use popup window in flex 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, popup, flex3, mxml

I have used a datagrid and one button in control bar. by clicking button the application goes edit state from base state.
My question is how can i use popup for editing selected record of datagrid instead of changing state.
please give me any example with code that describe how pop ups can be used in flex 3 application.

Comment: What do you need in particular? To migrate your states-based code to popup-based or you haven't idea how pop ups work in Flex? In first case you should provide your code (it is very difficult to give abstract migration advices in particular application). For the second case the best solution is RTFM. Please edit your question to give us an idea how to help you :)

Comment: @Constantiner I haven't any idea about how pop ups used in  flex. Can You brief about RTFM?

Comment: Ok. [This documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html) will help you :)

Comment: @Nate I mean explain in brief... I think It is a big concept.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer for above problem.
First we have to create custom component for popup named MyPopup

And in application:

```
import components.popups.MyPopup;
public var pop:MyPopup;
public function Show_Pop():void
            {

             pop= PopUpManager.createPopUp(this,MyPopup,true)  as MyPopup;
             PopUpManager.centerPopUp(pop);

             }
```

calling function:

```
<mx:Button  click="Show_Pop()" id="btn1" label="show Popup"/>
```